# Error in preview data explorer view in ckan

Tags: csv, jinja2, ckan

I have a ckan instance installed in a ubuntu 14 machine.

All seam to be ok except when I try to preview a resources view in data explored.

I am using the recline_view plugin to view the data. The resource is a simple csv file and it was exported to the datastore successfully.

I am using the datapusher plugin to send csv data to the datastore. The error that a get when try to preview the csv resource is the following:

```
⇝ HelperError: Helper 'get_mapview_config' has not been defined.
View as:   Interactive (full)  |  Text (full)  |  XML (full)
Module ckan.controllers.package:1568 in resource_view          view
>>  return h.rendered_resource_view(view, resource, package, embed=True)
Module ckan.lib.helpers:1954 in rendered_resource_view          view
>>  return literal(base.render(template, extra_vars=data_dict))
Module ckan.lib.base:174 in render          view
>>  return cached_template(template_name, render_template)
Module pylons.templating:249 in cached_template          view
>>  return render_func()
Module ckan.lib.base:128 in render_template          view
>>  return render_jinja2(template_name, globs)
Module ckan.lib.base:85 in render_jinja2          view
>>  return template.render(**extra_vars)
Module jinja2.environment:989 in render          view
>>  return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
Module jinja2.environment:754 in handle_exception          view
>>  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
Module /home/ubuntu/workspace/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/reclineview/theme/templates/recline_view.html:1 in top-level template code          view
>>  {% extends "base.html" %}
Module /home/ubuntu/workspace/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html:103 in top-level template code          view
>>  {%- block page %}{% endblock -%}
Module /home/ubuntu/workspace/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckanext/reclineview/theme/templates/recline_view.html:5 in block "page"          view
>>  {% set map_config = h.get_map_config() or h.get_mapview_config() %}
Module jinja2.environment:412 in getattr          view
>>  return obj[attribute]
Module ckan.lib.helpers:62 in __getitem__          view
>>  key=key
HelperError: Helper 'get_mapview_config' has not been defined.
```

What could be the problem? I there any configuration missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was reporter to the ckan community. Thera are a pull request that resolve the problem:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3235

You just have to pull this commit or just wait until it is merge to the master branch.